# SQL Query Builder for PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am a real dummie when it comes to SQL. Does anyone have a tool maybe that I could select what I want to do and have it output the sql query?

Thanks,
Blake

Comment: It's definitely worth your while to spend some time learning SQL. Spending a day or two just working through books/tutorials/examples will take you a long ways and benefit you tremendously.

Comment: Seconding @mfonda's comment.  You won't know what the tool is doing unless you know a little SQL.  And SQL is incredibly easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP / MySQL Query Builder UI with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000253/php-mysql-query-builder-ui-with-jquery)

Comment: If you have already checked the one linked duplicate above, please point out why the suggested solutions do not solve your problem. This will make it easier for others to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into phpMyAdmin, http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: I hate this tool, but if you really don't want anything to do with SQL syntax phpMyAdmin is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL **workbench** (Look inside the mysql.com) is a free tool and generates the whole sql code for you. Also phpMyAdmin do the job, but they are different tools for different reasons.

Comment: I have to say that I use phpMyAdmin frequently to manage my databases. However you can't get the SQL from it without actually executing the query. MYSQL workbench has a confirmation dialog that asks you to approve the SQl, which is nice.

Comment: with workbench you are able to draw the entities and retrieve the sql code, just right click of your mouse and copy SQL to clipboard.. Nice it help you, I use workbench frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat (the database manager) outputs the SQL in the bottom of the window.  This is true for deletion, insertion, ordering, etc.